# BIRT Variable - How to create and use?

Tags: java, html, birt

I need to create a global report variable to get a variable of my first table, then use it in my last table to do a calculation.

I'm new with BIRT and don't found a guide to do it.

Someone can explain me how I can do it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We initialize a global report variable in "Variables" section of the outline view:

[image: Global variable]

Then we can set and get its value from any place of the report:

```
myvalue=vars["myGlobalVariable"];

vars["myGlobalVariable"]=myvalue;
```

Notice global variables we declare like this are also available in the expression builder, which is very convenient.

Comment: Is it possible to declare a list variable? Or just int and strings?