# BIRT - using multiple webservices to get the data

Tags: web-services, report, birt

I am trying to generate a report using Eclipse BIRT report designer.

**The scenario is this:**

There are 2 web service data sources. There are 2 datasets for webservices 'WS1' and 'WS2' respectively.

The output element 'COUNTRYID' of one webservice 'WS1' would go as input for another webservice 'WS2'.

**What I did:**

- Created a parameter COUNTRYID.
- Created a dummy Computed Column in the dataset of the web service 'WS1' with the expression:

  ```
      params["COUNTRYID"].value=row["COUNTRYID"]
  ```
- Now the input parameters for the 'WS2' dataset is related to the global paramter 'COUNTRYID'.
- When I run the report, I see that the global parameter contains the value from the 'WS1' output.

But the report does not display the values from the response of the web service 'WS2'

**My questions:**

- How can I see, if the webservice got fired or not?
- How can I see, if the webservice got fired with correct values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS1 is not fired unless it is explicitely bound to a report element. Typically, to achieve this we apply following steps:

- insert a data element *at the beginning of the report body*
- turn the property visibility of this new element to false (or let it visible during testing)
- bind it to the first dataset WS1

It will force a silent execution of WS1, and therefore this will populate your parameter COUNTRYID before WS2 runs.

However this approach would not work if:

- WS2 dataset has to be used to populate selection items of a report parameter (which does not seem to be the case here)
- If COUNTRYID parameter is used at render time. This point is much more annoying, if you need this parameter in chart expressions for example. If so, i would recommend to store WS1 in a report variable instead of (or why not in addition to) a report parameter. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765715/birt-variable-how-to-create-and-use/19766349#19766349) to see how to create a report variable.

You can initialize it at the same place you did for the report parameter with:

```
vars["COUNTRYID"]=row["COUNTRYID"];
```

and use it anywhere with

```
vars["COUNTRYID"];
```

Report variables are available from the palette of expressions editor :

Comment: Thank you @Dominique ..  The order of firing seems to be the problem I had. With report parameters itself, I achieved, what was needed :)