# Display data from DataSet on every page header and footer

Tags: report, birt

I am trying to achieve what I thought was quite a simple function.

I have a logo and contact details which come from the data set. How can I put them in the header and/or footer of the report?

As far as I understood we cannot put table directly in the master page footer or header.

I also tried to use report variables but looks like header and footer are processed before data binding is available.

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE.
For the footer I ended up using a report variable which were initialised in the dataset OnFetch and used in footer control's OnRender. For the label Text property can be updated and for the Image - Data property accordingly. Also global javascript variables can be used for this purpose.
Interestingly, the same approach did not work for the header - it's processed before report variable is set and controls are always empty. So the only way is to wrap the main data table in another table and use it's header as a page header.

I just hope that Birt will be modified at some point to accommodate such a simple scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you cannot use 'data' directly on the masterpage.

**header**

Put you main content in a table that holds the main data. Find a way to group your data in a general way (so that the grouping should be redundand) and use the 'repeat header' checkbox to create a header/footer row in the table. You can now place the header details here. You should delete the group footer since it won't get repeated. You also might want to change the masterpage to remove the header. Set header height to 0.

**footer**

If you really need footers, you must use the footers on the masterpage. A way to sneak in data is to use variables. You can use the various scripts to update the content. I haven't tested this, but it should work. The final implementation depends quite heavily on your actual report. (see: [BIRT Variable - How to create and use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765715/birt-variable-how-to-create-and-use))

Comment: That's how I ended up implementing the report. I hoped I just missed something obvious in Birt which would allow me to do it "properly". I put it in update to the question.

Comment: then you should upvote and accept the answer (you will get points for that too)

Comment: Sorry, should have upvote it straight away. But do not want to mislead other users, neither your answer nor my update is the answer to the original problem.

Comment: This solution seems overly complicated, see my answer instead

Comment: It's more complicated because it also works for a more elaborate scenario where the details in the header/footer need differ per record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data from datasets in the masterpage's header and footer by binding the data set to a grid item. Of course, the data set should return a *single* row in that case.